# Mocking Interface using Moq - never hits the mocked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, moq

I am attempting to setup a simple unit test for my code. I have an interface and implementation that talks to an external service via WCF. I am attempting to mock this with the code below;

```
private Mock<IPayments> _mockIPayments;

_mockIPayments.Setup(x => x.GetCreditCard(It.IsAny<GetCreditCardRequest>())).Returns(getCreditCardResponse);
```

In the unit test itself, I create an instance of the service that would ultimately call the WCF service;

```
var paymentService = new PaymentService();

var response = paymentService.GetCardDetails(cardId);
```

Within the PaymentService itself, the code;

```
var response = ServiceInvoker.Invoke<IPayments, GetCreditCardRequest, GetCreditCardResponse>
                          (
                              "Payments",
                              request,
                              (proxy, req) => proxy.GetCreditCard(req));
```

(Note that ServiceInvoker.Invoke is just a wrapper to create a channel and process the request)

Am I missing something, should the mock setup not be catching the request to GetCreditCard?

ETA

To make it a little clearer, the flow is;

UnitTest -> PaymentsService -> IPayments

Comment: That's not how Moq works. Use _mockPaymentService.Object instead of paymentService

Comment: @Crowcoder _mockPaymentService is not PaymentService, but IPayments (which is the contract exposed on the WCF service). I have updated the example to reflect, which might make you change your comment?

Comment: In this specific code I don't know how you would use it but Moq does not intercept all subsequent calls like some frameworks ( MS Fakes for example). You must use the mock object where you would otherwise use the actual implementation. This is generally done in tandem with dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, I see where you are going. I tend to use rhino mocks which can do this interception. Perhaps I will refactor to use DI and pass in the mock.object as you suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your mocked instance to the service somehow.

```
var paymentService = new PaymentService(_mockIPayments.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply specifying a setup will not let Moq replace all instances of some interface with the what you specified. It simply defines what Moq will return when a certain `Mock` instance will be called. In your case `_mockIPayments`.

You then have to use that mocked `IPayments` instance in your code (either pass it in a constructor or method) for your code to actually use it.

If your `PaymentService` is currently creating an `IPayments` object internally, to use mocking you will have to use something like Dependency Injection so that you are able to specify the `IPayments` instance externally and thus supply a mock instance in your tests.

Likewise:

```
var paymentService = new PaymentService(_mockIPayments.Object);
```